# Is it possible to render different html for different environments using reactjs CRA

Tags: javascript, reactjs, environment-variables, create-react-app

Create React App generates a static html we use to bind our components to. I am wondering if we could change contents based on the environment we are in.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico">
  <title>React App</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="root"></div>
</body>
```

For example, if can I have title as `"develop"` & `"production"` depending on where the react app is running?

Can this be achieved just using reactjs env config file without any server side rendering?

edit: ...and without ejecting and dealing with webpack config?

Comment: If you mean the `title` tag you can use Helmet https://github.com/nfl/react-helmet

Comment: Got help for the title in CRA:- You can actually define a variable in `env` file and reference that in your title like so:

    <title>%REACT_APP_MY_PAGE_TITLE%</title>

This way you can define different titles for different envs like `env.local`, `env.production` e.t.c 

This was so neat, i hope it helps you

Comment: Question: what do you mean "without dealing with webpack config"? Do you not deploy your code with a build step to ensure your bundles built for the environment it's running in?

Comment: create-react-app's boilerplate takes care of the configs and for simple apps, you do not need to modify webpack - whcih requires you to eject https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#npm-run-eject

Answer (score 1):

I have a solution which can be done without using environment variables with an assumption **your develop and production urls are different**

You can fetch the current url from `window.location.href` and based on the url you can change the title of the react app.

However, I feel environment variables will be a better solution

Answer (score 0):

You'd better to run `npm run eject` in your CRA object. you will find a folder called `config`, to change the HtmlWebpackPlugin from  `webpack.config.dev.js` and `webpack.config.prod.js`:

```
…
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
  inject: true,
  template: **CHNAGE ME**,
…
```

Comment: thanks. sorry I just updated the question to not consider ejecting. Yours is probably a good solution but I prefer not dealing with configs too much.